# Dataframe question, concatenate 2 dataframes but avoid having empty rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 100 users and some small information. Now I want to create another dataframe and merge them, the new dataframe needs to have the same users but now includes new data and more data. so each user on the original dataframe now has 100 more datapoints in the new dataframe.

example for 2 users, and 4 datapoints on the 2nd dataframe

dataframe 1:

```
Name | Age | Username 
John | 20  | johndoe01
Johny| 24  | johnydoe02
```

Datafrane 2:

```
Username2 | Score | Accuracy
johndoe01 | 80    |   70%
johndoe01 | 50    |   50%
johndoe01 | 80    |   70%
johnydoe02 | 50    |   50%
johnydoe02 | 20    |   30%
johnydoe02 | 50    |   50%
```

Now , the second dataframe is easy to create , using the iterrow , however my goal is to  concatenate them so it looks like this :

```
  Name | Age |  Username2 | Score | Accuracy
  John | 20  |  johndoe01 | 80    |   70%
  John | 20  |  johndoe01 | 50    |   50%
  John | 20  |  johndoe01 | 80    |   70%
  Johny| 24  |  johnydoe02| 50    |   50%
  Johny| 24  |  johnydoe02| 20    |   30%
  Johny| 24  |  johnydoe02| 50    |   50%
```

again these are examples but I just want to basically create a 2nd dataframe using faker that generates multiple values per user from the first dataframe and then merge both dataframes  so they one big table.    My current approach is to use an iterrow on dataframe1 and per each row create a new dataframe with the same username and the other data, then concatenate this to the first dataframe and go on but does not give me the expected result which is the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is more of a merge operation. Set how='right' to include all rows from the second DataFrame. Also check out the 'indicator' input to handle any non-matches.

```py
result = df1.merge(df2, how='right', left_on='Username', right_on='Username2')

result.drop(columns='username', inplace=True)

    Name  Age   Username2  Score Accuracy
0   John   20   johndoe01     80      70%
1   John   20   johndoe01     50      50%
2   John   20   johndoe01     80      70%
3  Johny   24   johnydoe02     50      50%
4  Johny   24   johnydoe02     20      30%
5  Johny   24   johnydoe02     50      50%
```

Comment: ok, a small question nwo would be, how can I create the 2nd data frame with the same usernames as dataframe 1?  I think merge actually completes my idea.

Comment: using this with a loop on itterrows so I can try and mantain the usernames, since I dont know how can I create a second dataframe with the same usernames as dataframe 1,  merge will give me an error "cannot use name of an existing column for indicator column"  .

Comment: Can you just drop the username column? Edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: in theory I can , but the idea si that if dataframe1 has 10 users, then dataframe 2 should have 10 data per user in dataframe1. I think I got the idea with your concat, doing the itterrow and some coding I can create a good dataframe 2 iwth the corresponding usernames of dataframe 1 and then merge them and it works. Thank you