# Concatenating 2 DataFrames with DateTimeIndex but different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

What I am trying to achieve is basically checking which of the month and year of the 1st DataFrame matches that of the 2nd DataFrame, then entering the values respectively. The 2nd DataFrame will never have a month that is not in the 1st DataFrame as it is derived from some computations in the 1st DataFrame.

The following is the 1st DataFrame I have:

```
         Date  count
0  2010-01-02     14
1  2010-01-12     14
2  2010-01-23     16
3  2010-02-02     19
4  2010-02-13     20
5  2010-02-24     22
6  2010-03-03     28
7  2010-03-13     40
8  2010-03-24     60
9  2010-04-02     36
10 2010-04-14     24
11 2010-04-25     30
12 2010-05-05     34
13 2010-05-15     25
14 2010-05-26     22
15 2010-06-03     24
16 2010-06-14     29
17 2010-06-25     30
```

I would like to concatenate the following DataFrame with the above

```
      Date   new
0  2010-01   NaN
1  2010-02   NaN
2  2010-03  17.5
3  2010-04  25.0
4  2010-05  33.0
5  2010-06  27.5
```

such that the output becomes

```
         Date  count  new
0  2010-01-02     14  NaN
1  2010-01-12     14  NaN
2  2010-01-23     16  NaN
3  2010-02-02     19  NaN
4  2010-02-13     20  NaN
5  2010-02-24     22  NaN
6  2010-03-03     28 17.5
7  2010-03-13     40 17.5
8  2010-03-24     60 17.5
9  2010-04-02     36 25.0
10 2010-04-14     24 25.0
11 2010-04-25     30 25.0
12 2010-05-05     34 33.0
13 2010-05-15     25 33.0
14 2010-05-26     22 33.0
15 2010-06-03     24 27.5
16 2010-06-14     29 27.5
17 2010-06-25     30 27.5
```

Is there any clean way to do this? This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156082/dataframe-question-concatenate-2-dataframes-but-avoid-having-empty-rows) almost works, but requires me to create 2 new columns for the month and day, as far as I know, to join my 2 DataFrames, which I would like to avoid as they are huge and may take too much time to compute.

Comment: @Mr.T they are python datetime objects

Comment: have your tried pd.concatenate with axis=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add a new column to your first dataframe.

```
df1['new'] = df1['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m').map(df2.set_index(df2['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['new'])
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this solution and I got the error ```AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values.``` Could it be because .dt only works when there is a timestamp as well?

Comment: convert them to datetime first then. `df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])`, and do the same for `df2['Date']`

Comment: @RaymondKwok yup I just did that. turns out I forgot to do that with the original datafram